# Communication Exception and do reconnect automatic?

Tags: c#, wcf, fault

Say that I got a WCF client that communicates with a WCF service in IIS7(TCP) using channelfactory. If the communication is broken(or the service recycles) then the next call from the client will result in an exception.

At this point I need to hide the exception and instead try to make a reconnect/re-login.

**The question is** if there is any simple way to do this without adding handling code in every ServiceAgentMethod on the client side? Is this for example possible to solve with a MessageInspector?

In my case I got several Agent classes in the client that runs the service methods with a singular IServceInterface created from ChannelFactory. Something like this :

```
MyServiceAgent.GetService().GetMyObjects
```

The GetService() will return the IServiceInterface that is created on login by the ChannelFactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try it using a [message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx); when a channel faults, it faults *hard* (as you've seen, you get an exception).  It's used to indicate that the channel is no longer considered valid and that you shouldn't make calls on it.

You might think that you could do this at the transport layer, but you'd need coordination of the layers above it (in order to translate what comes in over the wire, which you really shouldn't have access to) in order to determine whether or not you have a fault.

Ultimately, you would want to issue retry logic at the level where you make the call to the proxy.  Have an abstraction of the client (an interface) which you intercept before/after you make the call to the proxy; if there's an exception, you can retry the call, creating a new proxy/channel as needed.

Be careful to put a limit on the number of retries you perform; if you don't you'll end up with a poison pill (your code will retry infinitely).  At some point, you'll *want* to throw  the exception.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with a interface of the client? A thought is to use some sort of delegate method. Say that the method rakes a delegate and returns a object. The method will try to run the delegate(against the service) and handle a reconnect if needed. The when a successfull call is done, return the object and let the agent method cast it to the correct type. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic consumer that you can use to make WCF calls. In the example provided you can specify the retry count and it handles tear down and re-create of the clients better.

This will still be on the client side but because it is generic and the complexities are hidden I think it makes for a elegant solution:

```
var consumer = new ServiceClientWrapper<AuthorServiceClient, AuthorService>();
author = consumer.Excecute(service => service.AddAuthor(request));
```

https://github.com/mariusvrstr/WcfClientStressTest/blob/master/Spike.Common/ServiceClientWrapper.cs